# Set up Wi-Fi country/regulatory domain with Netplan-generated wpa_supplicant conf

Tags: networking, netplan, wpa-supplicant

My current `/etc/netplan/wifi.yaml` looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "myssid":
          "mypw"
```

Then `netplan generate` produces `/run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
  ssid="myssid"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  psk="mypw"
}
```

How to add **`country=NL`** to it without losing it after the next `netplan generate`?

Or is there another way to specify the Wi-Fi region?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 64-bit, if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Netplan supports a `regulatory-domain: NL` setting, as of v0.105, so you should be able to adopt your configuration to something like this:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      regulatory-domain: "NL"
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "myssid":
          "mypw"
```

See: https://netplan.io/reference#properties-for-device-type-wifis

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Netplan v0.105 is available since Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score -1):

Just try the iw reg way:

## iw reg set

from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#Device_driver