# brcmfmac: cf880211_set_channel: set chanspec 0x1234 fail, reason -52

Tags: raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS on a rasberry Pi 4. I am attempting to connect the wifi to my school wifi. I am getting many of this error:

brcmfmac: cf880211_set_channel: set chanspec 0x1234 fail, reason -52

I have set up the network_manager in the same way I always do:

nmcli> set ipv4.method auto
nmcli> set 802-1x.eap peap
nmcli> set 802-1x.phase2-auth mschapv2
nmcli> set 802-1x.identity robotics@brandeis.edu
nmcli> set 802-1x.password "three words"
nmcli> set wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Pito

Comment: Has any previous OS worked at the school?

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Now I am thinking to try to install that ubuntu with balenaetch instead of the pi installer. The latter may be customizing or tweaking in a way that's somehow getting in the way of the nmcli settings that Ive used successfully in the past.

Comment: Rufus has proved to be the best and most reliable.

Comment: What is Rufus??

Comment: A quick Google search brings up this. https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: Windows only.Sigh

Answer (score 0):

That could mean you don't have your pi set to the right regulatory domain, so it thinks it is illegal to use the WiFi channel your school's WiFi is on. You can set the regulatory domain with netplan using the `regulatory-domain` setting, as in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1480856/164539

You should set it to the country code for whatever country you are in (e.g. `US` if you are in the united states).